# Force static compilation in stack

Tags: haskell, build, compilation, haskell-stack

I use `stack` with multiple projects, I need to have two ways to compile them a "normal one" for the day-to-day development and one for the deployment.

I use `hpack` and my projects look like that:

```
name:                test
version:             0.1.0
github:              "th/ng"
author:              "Me"
description:         Ok


dependencies:
- base >= 4.7 && < 5

executables:
  test-bootstrap:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
```

For my deployments I need to configure them as following:

```
executables:
  test-bootstrap:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    cc-options:          -static
    ld-options:          -static -pthread
    extra-lib-dirs:      ./.system-work/lib
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    - -static
```

Which forces me to run with `stack build --docker`.

I have tried to leverage `stack build --ghc-options "-static"`

But I have an horrible trace:

```
test          > /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /home/stackage/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/ghc-prim-0.5.3/libHSghc-prim-0.5.3.a(Classes.o): requires unsupported dynamic reloc 11; recompile with -fPIC
```

Is there a way to give `cc-options` and `ld-options` to `stack`, or to have multi-projects flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have leveraged the `Yaml` include mechanism, here is my `flags.yaml` for static compilation:

```
- &deployed_exe
  cc-options:          -static
  ld-options:          -static -pthread
  extra-lib-dirs:      ./.system-work/lib
  ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    - -static
```

And my `package.yaml`s:

```
_flags: !include "../flags.yaml"


executables:
  test-bootstrap:
    <<: *deployed_exe
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
```

I have a symbolic link I switch depending of my needs.